# How to find probability of image pixel belonging to a cluster in OpenCV-Python library?

Tags: python, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

If `P(x belongs to k = i) | F )`, for `i={1,2,3}`. `F` is the frequency of a pixel `x` assignment to a cluster, or, in other words, how salient the assignment of `x` to the `i-th` cluster is, or even how often a pixel "jumps" to a different cluster.  So, each of the calculated maps (one for each cluster "identity"), indicates how often each pixel is assigned to the given cluster. To convert into probability, you will need to normalize into `[0,1]`.

How can I achieve the above problem? Your help would be appreciated!!!

My code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read in the image
original_image = cv2.imread("someImage.jpg")

# Change the color of the image to RGB
img=cv2.cvtColor(original_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Reshape the image into a 2D array of pixels and 3 color values (RGB)
vectorized = img.reshape((-1,3))
vectorized

# Convert to float type
vectorized = np.float32(vectorized)
vectorized

# Criteria for the algorithm to stop running
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.85)
criteria

# Then perform k-means clustering
k=3
attempts=5
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(vectorized,k,None,criteria,attempts,cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS)
ret, label, center

# Convert data into 8-bit values 
center = np.uint8(center)
res = center[label.flatten()]

# Reshape data into the original image dimensions 
result_image = res.reshape((img.shape))

# Show the results
figure_size = 15
plt.figure(figsize=(figure_size,figure_size))
plt.subplot(1,2,1),plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(1,2,2),plt.imshow(result_image)
plt.title('Segmented Image when k = %i' % k), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```